# AutoMapper global configuration - convert null array property to empty array by default

Tags: c#, automapper

I am upgrading `AutoMapper` from version `3` to `8` and I have some broken tests where the `null` conversion behaviour has changed. I am still using the static API. Before, when I had an object to be mapped with an `int[]` property which was `null`, without specifying a `ForMember` conversion, it would create an empty array. Consider these classes:

```
    public class From
    {
        public int[] Ids { get; set; }
    }

    public class To
    {
        public int[] Ids { get; set; }
    }
```

Calling the following code results in an exception within `AutoMapper`:

```
var from = new From
{
    Ids = null
};
var @to = Mapper.Map<From, To>( from ); //KABOOM!!!
Assert.NotNull( @to.Ids );
```

Exception:
`System.ArgumentException : System.Int32[] needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args.`

When they are mapped like so:

```
Mapper.Initialize(
                config => {
                    config.CreateMap<From, To>();

                    config.AllowNullDestinationValues = false;
                    config.AllowNullCollections = true;

                    config.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
                } );
```

I tried adding an explicit converter for `int[]` like this but it did not work:

`config.CreateMap<int[], int[]>().ConvertUsing( x => x ?? new int[ 0 ] );`

And I also tried removing the `CreateMap<From, To>()` line and it's still not working.

I know I can add a `ForMember` mapping to achieve this but we have possibly hundreds of types implicitly depending on this behaviour so I want to be able to configure it globally/have it work as-is.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a bug. But it does work with AllowNullDestinationValues true and AllowNullCollections false;